# What is the unit measurement used in edquota?

Tags: quota

I have the following quota setting for ec2-user:

```
Disk quotas for user ec2-user (uid 500): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/xvdf      32*      1       1   6days       8       0       0
```

However, when I donwload files with 3.1 MB it still works, then I try a new file with 1.5Gb and it still works, no warning or error messages show up.

What is the unit measurement for the quota soft and hard limit in this case? E.g: bytes or mb or gb?

Answer (score 2):

> Block quotas can be specified in bytes (B), kilobytes (K), megabytes (M), terabytes (T), petabytes (P), or exabytes (E).  If no units are specified, kilobytes are    assumed.  Inode quotas can be specified in kiloinodes   (K), megainodes (M), terainodes (T), petainodes (P), or exainodes (E).  If no units are specified, the number of inodes speci-
>        fied are used.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?edquota(8)